# Microsoft Teams Custom App doesn't work on Android mobile

Tags: android, mobile, tabs, microsoft-teams

I'm testing the custom tab on Microsoft Teams app.
It correctly works on Desktop and iPhone, but it doesn't work on the Android mobile app.
[The Android mobile debug screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Engs0.png)
I'd like to know Why it's canceled?
[The Android mobile couldn't open the app's web page.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYfic.jpg)

I've captured the packet on the webserver when the android clicked the custom tab.
I could see only the server key exchange process, there is no client key exchange.
[Android mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gnQe.png)

The iPhone was working properly and there was the client key exchange process.
[iPohne](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4YJq.png)

Please advise me.

Refferred to the below source code:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const env = require('node-env-file');
const path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
env(path.join(__dirname, '../.env'));
const config = require('./config/config');
const { logger } = require('./logger/logger');
const fs = require('fs');
const https = require('https');
const nocache = require('nocache');
const app = express();
const api = require('./api');
app.use(morgan('combined'));
app.enable('trust proxy');
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '5mb' }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: '5mb', extended: true, parameterLimit: 50000 }));
app.use(cors());
app.use(nocache());
app.use(cookieParser())
app.use('/api', api);
// Login Authenticate
if (config.loginMode === 'local') {
  require('./passport')
}
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  // Vue Router
  app.use(require('connect-history-api-fallback')());
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../../dist')));
}
// MongoDB Connection
require('./db')
const options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('./keys/evm.ecstel.co.kr.key', 'utf8'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('./keys/evm_ecstel_co_kr.crt', 'utf8')
}
// Server Running
const server = https.createServer(options, app).listen(process.env.PORT || config.port, function () {
  logger.info(`Server started on https`)
  logger.info(`Server started on port ${config.port} in ${config.host}`)
})
```

Comment: Could you please share the sample code or docs that you are following, so that we can test it from our end?

Comment: I referred to the below link for implementation.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/sbs-gs-nodejs?tutorial-step=3

Comment: @YK.KIM - Could you please share repro steps and sample code to try at our end?

Comment: To debug your Tab from the Android side : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/developer-tools#access-devtools-from-an-android-device

Comment: @YK.KIM - Could you please Install this manifest and check its working for you.
https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/blob/main/demo%20manifest/Tab-Product-Inspection.zip

Comment: @Nivedipa-MSFT I attached the sample code file, please refer to the reademe.txt for testing it.
https://ecsadmin-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/ykkim_ecsadmin_onmicrosoft_com/ETDVGqkMyU9LuKxViZLTPTIBNVQ9PUyadlMwpL4lAdiYgQ?e=VQi9h4

Comment: @Nivedipa-MSFT I did install the manifest and it's working well. But when I change the Urls(websiteUrl,privacyUrl,teamOfUserUrl) to my web address(https://evm.ecstel.co.kr), it still didn't work on the android mobile. Else browsers were working properly(iPhone safari, pc Chrome, ms edge).

Comment: @YK.KIM - Have you added the evm.ecstel.co.kr url in validdomain in manifest file?
Could you please check the application on desktop Teams client if its working or not.

Comment: @Nivedipa-MSFT Yes, I added the URL to validdomains section. The desktop Teams client worked well. Only android mobile didn't work properly.

Comment: @YK.KIM - Have you added the url in validdomain with https like https://evm.ecstel.co.kr

Comment: Yes, I just added the url evm.ecstel.co.kr

Comment: @ChetanSharma-msft The Android mobile still had not worked.
One thing, my server is configured as a public IP address. so there is no reverse proxy. 
The android only could not change the client key with my webserver.
As a test when I set the webserver behind a proxy like a ngrok, the android mobile is working properly.

Comment: @YK.KIM - Did you check in the deployed version. I think it works there

Comment: @YK.KIM - Did you check in the deployed version?